# Date comparison in azure logic app get entities connector

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-table-storage

I have a logic app , which needs to pickup records from azure table storage based on a condition where  event_time (one of the field in table) >= current time +24 (hrs)

I have tried to implement  above logic as

[image]

I am getting following error

```
{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "InvalidInput",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en-US",
      "value": "')' or operator expected at position 24 in '(event_date_time gt 2020-10-06T21:52:30.2795067Z)'.
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any  way to  implement above logic in azure logic app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, you can refer to my logic app below:

[image]

The expression of `addToTime(...)` is same with yours, and please notice there is a pair of `''` on both sides of `addToTime(...)`. And please also pay attention to the case of your field, I test with field `TESTDATE` in "**Filter Query**" but it doesn't work. So if exists upper case and lower case in your `event_date_time`, please use the original letter in "**Filter Query**".