# How to Calculate date difference in hours in logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-table-storage

I have azure table with following properties

- event_name  (string)
- event_date_time  (dateTime)
- status  (string)

From logic app I need to  fetch all records which satisfies following condition

current time <= event_date_time <= current_date_time + 24 hours

I am using logic Get Entities connector  . I am not sure how to implement above logic .
Is there any  date difference function which will return difference in hours ?

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution I provided below helps your problem ? If still have any problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar solution with your another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64216759/date-comparison-in-azure-logic-app-get-entities-connector/64237994#64237994), just use "Filter Query" like below:

[image]